# How can I update fields automatically in easy admin 4?

Tags: event-listener, easyadmin, symfony6

I have a sale entity in Easy Admin. I want to update dollar amount fields (Delivery Amount, Subtotal, Sale Total) when items are added via the crud form. I have an AfterEntityUpdate Event which does work and will adjust those fields after the update is saved. What I can't seems to get is the same behavior for an AfterEntityPersisted Event after it's created for the first time. I'm not sure if this is even the correct way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

My Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\SaleRepository;
use App\Entity\Customer;
use App\Entity\Inventory;
use App\Entity\Packages;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SaleRepository::class)]
class Sale
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private ?string $OrderType = 'REGULAR SALE';

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $ExternalSalesOrderNumber;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $DeliveryDate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 3, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $ShipViaCode = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $PaymentMethod = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 3, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $TaxCode = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true)]
    private ?float $SaleAmount = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float', nullable: true)]
    private ?float $TaxAmount = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
    private ?float $TotalAmount = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
    private ?float $DeliveryAmount = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'SalesWritten')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?\App\Entity\User $salesperson = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Customer::class, inversedBy: 'sales_orders')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?\App\Entity\Customer $customer = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $BcOrderNumber = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $BcStatus = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $PsStatus = 'Pending';

    private $subtotal;
    private $tax;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::ARRAY, nullable: true)]
    private ?array $SalePkgQuantities = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: packages::class, inversedBy: 'PackageSales')]
    private Collection $SalePkgItems;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'sale', targetEntity: SaleLineItems::class, cascade: ["persist", "remove"])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    private Collection $SaleLineItems;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?float $TaxPercentage = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->SalePkgItems = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->SaleLineItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return strval($this->ExternalSalesOrderNumber);
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getOrderType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->OrderType;
    }

    public function setOrderType(string $OrderType): self
    {
        $this->OrderType = $OrderType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getExternalSalesOrderNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ExternalSalesOrderNumber;
    }

    public function setExternalSalesOrderNumber(int $ExternalSalesOrderNumber): self
    {
        if($ExternalSalesOrderNumber === null){
            $this->ExternalSalesOrderNumber = $this->getId() + 100000;

            return $this;
        }
        $this->ExternalSalesOrderNumber = $ExternalSalesOrderNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->DeliveryDate;
    }

    public function setDeliveryDate(?\DateTimeInterface $DeliveryDate): self
    {
        $this->DeliveryDate = $DeliveryDate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShipViaCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ShipViaCode;
    }

    public function setShipViaCode(?string $ShipViaCode): self
    {
        $this->ShipViaCode = $ShipViaCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPaymentMethod(): ?string
    {
        return $this->PaymentMethod;
    }

    public function setPaymentMethod(?string $PaymentMethod): self
    {
        $this->PaymentMethod = $PaymentMethod;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTaxCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->TaxCode;
    }

    public function setTaxCode(?string $TaxCode): self
    {
        $this->TaxCode = $TaxCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSaleAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->SaleAmount;
    }

    public function setSaleAmount(?float $SaleAmount): self
    {
        $this->SaleAmount = $SaleAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTaxAmount(): ?float
    {
        
        return $this->TaxAmount;
    }

    public function setTaxAmount(?float $TaxAmount): self
    {
        if($this->TaxAmount === null){
            $this->TaxAmount = ($this->getSaleAmount() + $this->getDeliveryAmount()) * $this->getTaxPercentage();

            return $this;
        };
        $this->TaxAmount = $TaxAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->TotalAmount;
    }

    public function setTotalAmount(float $TotalAmount): self
    {

        if($this->TotalAmount === null){
            $this->TotalAmount = $this->getSaleAmount() + $this->getDeliveryAmount() + $this->getTaxAmount();

            return $this;
        };
        $this->TotalAmount = $TotalAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeliveryAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->DeliveryAmount;
    }

    public function setDeliveryAmount(float $DeliveryAmount): self
    {
        $this->DeliveryAmount = $DeliveryAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalesperson(): ?User
    {
        return $this->salesperson;
    }

    public function setSalesperson(?User $salesperson): self
    {
        $this->salesperson = $salesperson;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCustomer(): ?Customer
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }

    public function setCustomer(?Customer $customer): self
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBcOrderNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->BcOrderNumber;
    }

    public function setBcOrderNumber(?int $BcOrderNumber): self
    {
        $this->BcOrderNumber = $BcOrderNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBcStatus(): ?string
    {
        return $this->BcStatus;
    }

    public function setBcStatus(?string $BcStatus): self
    {
        $this->BcStatus = $BcStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPsStatus(): ?string
    {
        $PsStatus = $this->PsStatus;

        return $PsStatus;
    }

    public function setPsStatus(?string $PsStatus): self
    {
        $this->PsStatus = $PsStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSalePkgQuantities(): array
    {
        return $this->SalePkgQuantities;
    }

    public function setSalePkgQuantities(?array $SalePkgQuantities): self
    {
        $this->SalePkgQuantities = $SalePkgQuantities;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Packages>
     */
    public function getSalePkgItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->SalePkgItems;
    }

    public function addSalePkgItem(Packages $salePkgItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->SalePkgItems->contains($salePkgItem)) {
            $this->SalePkgItems->add($salePkgItem);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSalePkgItem(Packages $salePkgItem): self
    {
        $this->SalePkgItems->removeElement($salePkgItem);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, SaleLineItems>
     */
    public function getSaleLineItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->SaleLineItems;
    }

    public function addSaleLineItem(SaleLineItems $saleLineItem): self
    {
        if (!$this->SaleLineItems->contains($saleLineItem)) {
            $this->SaleLineItems->add($saleLineItem);
            $saleLineItem->setSale($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSaleLineItem(SaleLineItems $saleLineItem): self
    {
        if ($this->SaleLineItems->removeElement($saleLineItem)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($saleLineItem->getSale() === $this) {
                $saleLineItem->setSale(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTaxPercentage(): ?float
    {
        return $this->TaxPercentage;
    }

    public function setTaxPercentage(float $TaxPercentage): self
    {
        $this->TaxPercentage = $TaxPercentage;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My AfterPersisted Listener

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\AfterEntityPersistedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use App\Repository\InventoryRepository;

class AfterPersistedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public function __construct(private InventoryRepository $inventoryRepository){

    }

    public function onAfterEntityPersistedEvent(AfterEntityPersistedEvent $event): void
    {
        dump($event);
        $sale = $event->getEntityInstance();

        if(!$sale instanceOf Sale){
            return;
        }
        //dump($sale);
        $id = $sale->getId();
        //dump($id);
        $sale->setExternalSalesOrderNumber($id + 100000);
        $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $data = $sale->getSaleLineItems();
        
        if($data !== null){
            $prices = array();
            foreach($data as $item){
                //dump($item);
                $itm = $this->inventoryRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $item->getItem()]);
                dump($itm);
                $price = $itm->getPrice() /100;
                array_push($prices, $price);
            }
            $subtotal = array_sum($prices);
            //dump($subtotal);
            $ship = $sale->getShipViaCode();
            if($ship === 'OD'){
                $sale->setDeliveryAmount(95);
                $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
            else{
                $sale->setDeliveryAmount(0);
                $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
                $this->entityManager->flush();
            }
            $delivery = $sale->getDeliveryAmount();
            //dump($delivery);

            $salestax = $sale->getTaxPercentage();
            $tax = ($subtotal + $delivery) * $salestax;
            $total = $subtotal + $delivery + $tax;
            $sale->setSaleAmount($subtotal);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $sale->setTaxAmount($tax);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $sale->setTotalAmount($total);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            
        }
        else{
            $subtotal = 0;
            $sale->setDeliveryAmount(0);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $sale->setSaleAmount($subtotal);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $sale->setTaxAmount($tax);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            $sale->setTotalAmount($total);
            $this->entityManager->persist($sale);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        };
        dump($sale);
        dd("This should work");
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterEntityPersistedEvent::class => 'onAfterEntityPersistedEvent',
        ];
    }
}
```

I've tried custom form types as per symfony docs examples, but I couldn't get the field to generate. Other event listeners don't seem to produce the behavior I want.